# Querying Term Posts in Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, query

I'm trying to show my CPT Category along with any posts associated with it below the title. I have the first loop fine:

```
<?php $cats = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'custtax', 'orderby' => 'term_group')); 
    if(!empty($cats)) : 
        foreach($cats as $cat) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>
                <br />
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php $cat_posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'custcpt', 'taxonomy' => 'custtax', 'terms' => $cat->slug, 'order' => 'ASC'));
            foreach($cat_posts as $cat_post) : ?>

                    <center><?php get_the_post_thumbnail($cat_post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></center>
                        <br />
                    <a href="<?php get_permalink($cat_post->ID); ?>"><?php get_the_title($cat_post->ID); ?></a>
                        <br />
                        <br />

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But my second loop queries all my posts instead of just the ones from that category. I've tried `get_posts()` and instead of pulling all posts it didn't pull any. I'm not sure if `'category'` in the codex is expecting a string, slug, or ID, but I've tried all 3. Anyway how do I edit my query to only pull posts from that certain category?

Comment: See [`WP_Query` Taxonomy_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for how to correctly format a taxonomy query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer from @s_ha_dum - you need to modify a few things about your query.

First, use his suggested tax query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custcpt', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custtax', 
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat->term_id,
        )
    ), 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Then, modify your code as follows:

```
$cat_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while ($cat_posts->have_posts()) :
    $cat_posts->the_post(); 
    // Below, when referencing the post variables, must be as $cat_post->post->ID, etc. ?>
    <center><?php get_the_post_thumbnail($cat_post->post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></center>
    <br />
    <?php // Below, don't need to pass the post ID into these functions.  ?>
    <a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title(); ?></a>
                    <br />
                    <br />

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Note a few things:

1. You must use `while ($cat_posts->have_posts)` to iterate over the
   posts.
2. Call `cat_posts->the_post()` to prepare the data to be displayed in the functions such as `get_the_title()`
3. When referencing post variables, such as ID, you must do so as  `$cat_posts->post->ID`
4. When calling functions such as `get_the_title()`, you do *not* need to pass the ID in.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and what you have is not that.

```
$cat_posts = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'custcpt', 
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custtax', 
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $cat->term_id,
      )
    ), 
    'order' => 'ASC'
  )
);
```

Comment: Still not pulling any posts, but i'll keep playing around with it

Comment: @Howdy_McGee probably because you can't loop over a WP_Query object with foreach, it's an object not an array.

Comment: @Milo so is `get_posts()` a better option then?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee you can use `WP_Query`, you just need a loop: `while( $cat_posts->have_posts() ): $cat_posts->the_post()`, etc..

Comment: @Howdy_McGee : I rarely use anything but `WP_Query`.

Comment: Would I need to reset it right before the WP_Query, since i'm using it in a loop?